# how to call multiple function of same class in overflow manner

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript class

```
class Create {
  element = '';
  constructor(element) {
    this.element = document.createElement(element);
  }
  withClass(classname) {
    this.element.setAttribute('class', classname);
    return this.element;
  }
  withId(idName) {
    this.element.setAttribute('id', id);
    return this.element;
  }
}
```

in the file1.js. In the same file I am creating the instance of the class.

```
let cr = new Create('div').withClass('classname')
```

what i want to do is I want to create the object in this way

```
let cr = new Create('div').withClass('classname').withId('idname')
```

I know that this approach is like package=>class=>function instead of class=>function=>function

Is it even possible to do something like that or we have to use it in double lines;

Thanks

Comment: `return this.element;` ---> `return this;` Not related to your question but you should also fix the typo in `withId` method: `.setAttribute('id', id);` ---> `.setAttribute('id', idName);`

Comment: You'll find that if you format your code correctly, it's considerably easier to read. This is important when you're asking for help.

Comment: This is called function chaining, to do this you will have to return `this` and not `this.element` at the end of each function.

Comment: Assuming you want to get the element of the instance or alternatively chain the methods, achieving both is not simple. You can return only a single value from a method, and the method doesn't know how its return value will be used (it's possible, take a look at [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)). When you want to chain, you've to return `this`, when you want to get the element, you've to return `this.element`.

Comment: If this isn't a generic question it's probably better to create a function that will accept something like `(tagName: string, className?: string, id?: string, attributes?: {[name: string]: string}) => HTMLElement` (or you could also do the same thing with 1 object parameter)

Comment: @spender I will take care next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this without hacking at the DOM class prototypes (bad bad bad) or monkeypatching each created element (bad).

How about renaming `Create` to `ElementBuilder`, following @Yousaf's suggestion to return `this` and adding a `getElement` function member:

```
class ElementBuilder{
  element = '';
  constructor(element) {
    this.element = document.createElement(element);
  }
  withClass(classname) {
    this.element.setAttribute('class', classname);
    return this;
  }
  withId(idName) {
    this.element.setAttribute('id', id);
    return this;
  }
  getElement() {
    return this.element
  }
}
```

Then:

```
let cr = new ElementBuilder('div')
             .withClass('classname')
             .withId('idname')
             .getElement();
```

Comment: since `element` is a property of the object you don't need to add `getElement`, you can just use `.element` at the end of the chain.

Comment: @nickzoum I'd probably take steps to hide the underlying member here, but a getter onto it might be appropriate. Aesthetically, in a fluent-interface, I prefer the function call here. Horses-for-courses :)